# Django set headers on redirect()

Tags: django, redirect

I am trying the method in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31785096/add-request-header-before-redirection/31790410#31790410).  Something like this:

```
url = 'https://InternalURL'
token = 'api token here'
response = redirect(url)
response['Token'] = token
return response
```

This code lives in a view that is called when clicking a link in a template.  Some things are performed to build the correct url & get the api token prior to this code.

If I inspect the requests through Fiddler, the first redirect that has the 302 status code contains the headers I set.  But the subsequent request that attempts to navigate to the actual url I want to redirect to, the headers I need are not set.

Obviously that results in the request failing since the authentication token doesn't exist in the header.

Am I completely missing something obvious?  Is there a better way to do this?
Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Well that's an http concept problem I think. If you set a header in the response that is not a cookie, your client must set it manually again.

Comment: Hmm.. So do you perhaps have any suggestions on how to accomplish that, or go about this a different way?

Comment: set it as a cookie with `set_cookie` see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622793/django-cookies-how-can-i-set-them

Answer (score 0):

try the code below, It worked for me

```
 base_url = '/dashboard/'  # 1 /<redirect-route>
 query_string =  urlencode({'token': jwt.encode(payload, "SECRET PHRASE")})  # 2 token=jwt-token
 url = '{}?{}'.format(base_url, query_string)  # 3 /<redirect-route>/?token=jwt-token
        return redirect(url)
```

And you can retrieve at the view like

```
token = request.GET.get('token')
```

I don't know if it is the best way, but yes it worked in my case.