# Attach headers to redirect in Django

Tags: django, redirect, python-requests, http-status-code-403

In my view, I want to redirect to a URL (which points to a hosted image) but also add the `User-Agent` header to that GET request (to avoid 403 errors). I've explored two options:

1. The `redirect(url)` Django function. Is there a way to somehow add on headers?
2. Using the `requests` library:

   ```
   r = requests.get(picture.url, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent,})
   ```

   But then what should I return from my view? `return r`, `return r.content` or `return json()` didn't work for me.

== EDIT AFTER DUPLICATE QUESTION SOLUTION ==

As suggested, I tried the solution as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31785096/add-request-header-before-redirection):

```
def my_view(request):
    response = redirect("www.somewebsite.com/image.png")
    response['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla..."
    return response
```

But that didn't help with the 403 error when fetching `image.png`. I want to make sure that headers are added to the GET request fetching the image, not to the response returned by the view.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add request header before redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31785096/add-request-header-before-redirection)

Comment: Thanks, I tried it before but it doesn't seem to work in my scenario. Please see my edit above.